# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'destroyALLWindows'

Tags: opencv

I am currently using Win10 under python2.7.14 and opencv3.2.0 when I run the following snippet of code.

```css
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyALLWindows()
elif k == ord('s'): # wait for 's' key to save and exit 
    cv2.imwrite('messigray.png',img)
    cv2.destroyALLWindows()
```

Comment: [Spelling](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#destroyallwindows) -- the "ALL" should be "All". Wouldn't hurt to check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I made a stupid mistake! I mistook AllWindows for ALLWindows...